# C++ atomic acquire / release operations what it actually means

Tags: c++, atomic

I was going thru [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) page and trying to understand Memory model synchronization modes. In below example extracted from there:

```
 -Thread 1-       -Thread 2-
 y = 1            if (x.load() == 2)
 x.store (2);        assert (y == 1)
```

to which states that the store to 'y' happens-before the store to x in thread 1. Is 'y' variable here a normal global variable or is atomic?

Further if the load of 'x' in thread 2 gets the results of the store that happened in thread 1, it must all ***see all operations that happened before the store in thread 1***, even unrelated ones.

So what it means that x.store() operation would mean that all read / write to memory should have respective memory data values updated?

Then for std::memory_order_relaxed means "**no thread can count on a specific ordering from another thread**" - what does it means - is it that reordering will be done by compiler that value of y meynot be updated even though y.store() is called?

```
-Thread 1-
y.store (20, memory_order_relaxed)
x.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)

-Thread 2-
if (x.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)
  {
    assert (y.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 20) /* assert A */
    y.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)
  }

-Thread 3-
if (y.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)
  assert (x.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 10) /* assert B */
```

For Acquire / release memory model is similar to the sequentially consistent mode, except it only applies a happens-before relationship to dependent variables.

```
Assuming 'x' and 'y' are initially 0:


 -Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 3-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 20 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0)

 -Thread 4-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 10)
```

What does it means in explicit terms?

Comment: Try read this helpful page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
 -Thread 1-       -Thread 2-
 y = 1            if (x.load() == 2)
 x.store (2);        assert (y == 1)
```

1. Naturally, compiler may change order of operations that are not dependent to boost performance.
   But when **std::memory_order_seq_cst** is in action, any atomic operator works as [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).
   This does not mean *variable y* is the atomic, compiler just guarantees that `y = 1;` happens before `x.store (2);`. If there was another *thread 3* that manipulates *variable y*, assertion may fail due to the other thread.
   If my explanation is hard to understand(due to my poor English...) please check [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) & [happened-before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before).
   If *A* happened before *B* relationship is made, all threads must see the side-effect of *A* if *B*'s side-effect has been sighted.

```cpp
-Thread 1-
y.store (20, memory_order_relaxed)  // 1-1
x.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)  // 1-2

-Thread 2-
if (x.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)  // 2-1
  {
    assert (y.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 20) /* assert A */
    y.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)    // 2-2
  }

-Thread 3-
if (y.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)  // 3-1
  assert (x.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 10) /* assert B */
```

2. To understand **std::memory_order_relaxed**, you need to understand *[data dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency)*. Clearly, `x` & `y` does not have any dependency to each other. So compiler may change the order of  execution for *thread 1*, unlike **std::memory_order_seq_cst**, where `y.store(20)` **MUST** executed before `x.store(10)` happens.
   Let's see how each assertion may fail. I've added tag for each instruction.
   **assert A** : 1-2 → 2-1 → **assert A FAILED**
   **assert B** : See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065770/confused-about-atomic-class-memory-order-relaxed/46068191) for detailed answer.
   In short summary, *thread 3* may see final updated *variable y* and get 10, but not the side-effect of `1-2`. Even tho *thread 2* must have seen it's side-effect in order to store 10 into y, compiler does not guarantee instruction's side effect must have synchronized between threads(*happens-before*)
   On the other hand, below example from the [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) is example of instruction's order preserved when instructions have data dependency. `assert(y <= z)` is guaranteed to be passed.

```cpp
-Thread 1-
x.store (1, memory_order_relaxed)
x.store (2, memory_order_relaxed)

-Thread 2-
y = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
z = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
assert (y <= z)
```

2-2. *is it that reordering will be done by compiler that value of y may not be updated even though y.store() is called?*
**NO**. As I've described in 2., it means compiler may change the order of instructions that does not have  data dependency. Of course *y* must be updated when `y.store()` is called. After all, that's the definition of atomic instruction.

```cpp
Assuming 'x' and 'y' are initially 0:


 -Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 3-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 20 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0)

 -Thread 4-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 10)
```

3. Consistent mode requires *happens-before* relationship to all data. So under consistent mode, `y.store()` must happens-before `x.store()` or vice versa.
   If *thread 3*'s assert gets passed, it means `y.store()` *happened before* `x.store()`. So *thread 4* must have seen `y.load() == 20` before `x.load() == 10`. Therefore assert is failed. Same thing happens if *thread 4*'s assert gets passed.
   acquire / release memory model does not enforce *happens-before* relationship to independent variables. So below order can be made without violating any rules.
   *thread 4* `y.load()` → *thread 1* `y.store()` → *thread 3* `y.load()` → *thread 3* `x.load()` → *thread 4* `x.load()`
   Resulting both assertion gets passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation - it helped me to understand the concept